# Error installing ruby gem (Windows)

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

I am trying to install the Ruby openxml-docx gem. At first I got an error that asked me to install MSYS, so I did, but now it shows me the following error:

```
>gem install openxml-docx
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing openxml-docx:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ox-2.9.2/ext/ox
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180501-2696-1ds110t.rb extconf.rb
>>>>> Creating Makefile for ruby version 2.5.1 on x64-mingw32 <<<<<
creating Makefile
extconf.rb:67:in ``': No such file or directory - make clean (Errno::ENOENT)
    from extconf.rb:67:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby25- 
x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ox-2.9.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64- mingw32/2.5.0/ox-2.9.2/gem_make.out
```

Anybody knows how to solve this? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Is there anything worth sharing in `C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64- mingw32/2.5.0/ox-2.9.2/gem_make.out`?

Comment: Nope, that file says the same that was stated in the command line.

Comment: Gem installs fine for me (Ruby 2.3 on Windows 7). I'm using DevKit though, not MSYS/MINGW. Maybe that's the issue?